# Can Ethereum contract execute transactions directly on Bitcoin?

Tags: ethereum, bitcoin

Can an Ethereum contract execute transactions directly on the Bitcoin network? Ethereum contracts must be pure functions without any external side effects, and committing a transaction on another blockchain would be an external side effect, so I would assume this is not possible. What options would be possible for this sort of scenario?

Answer (score -1):

> *Can an Ethereum contract execute transactions directly on the Bitcoin network?*

Not directly. Ethereum and Bitcoin are two separate networks with different architecture and without any "official" bridge.

---

However, I could imagine a wild scenario that involves creating a BTC transaction based on Ethereum transaction:

1. User makes a transaction to an Ethereum address
2. An **external app** is listening to incoming transactions to this Ethereum address. When it learns about the new (Ethereum) transaction, it creates a BTC transaction object, signs it and broadcasts it to the Bitcoin network.

It's based on the way how some oracles work. They are listening to incoming transactions containing instructions, fetching some off-chain data (based on the instructions) and sending a new Ethereum tx that passes the off-chain data to a smart contract.

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I was thinking. Of course, an Oracle is a centralized service, useful for linking to the outside physical world. I was hoping for a decentralized solution. Perhaps we need a decentralized oracle blockchain so we do not have to put centralized trust in in to it.